# Simple Menu System Perl

Tags: perl, menu, ncurses

I'm trying to have 10-20 commands I run (centos) on a simple menu, Instead of writing from scratch, I was thinking of using ncurses or something similar to this image, very basic

[image: Sample]

Then that would run whatever command, maybe pause at the end when completed and thats it.
I looked for a while for a basic example menu to grab and go and no luck.
Found a ton of references with 90% simply dead links, outdated etc.
If someone has either an example using curses or a better simple way for me to just have a bunch of console commands run from the menu, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: In a shell script, I'd say to use `dialog(1)`. In perl... quick search of CPAN reveals [`Dialog`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dialog). It's old, though, and I've never used it, so no idea how well it works these days.

Comment: Also old and untested: [`Cmenu`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cmenu). There's probably other modules too if you search around.

Comment: Dialog's sources include a perl wrapper (see [source](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/dialog.pl)).  As usual, *ymmv*

Comment: Thanks I'll look into those, I was focused on the bigger name sort of with curses/ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [Curses::UI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI) and a [Curses::UI::Listbox](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses::UI::Listbox) to display the menu:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses::UI;

my $cui = Curses::UI->new( -color_support => 1 );
my $win1 = $cui->add('win1', 'Window');

my $listbox = $win1->add(
    'lb',
    'Listbox',
    -vscrollbar => 'left',
    -title      => "Select Playlist",
    -border     => 1,
    -wraparound => 1,
    -values     => [ "Radio",
                 "Recently added",
                 "SD-Alternative",
                 "SD-Country",
                 "SD-Pop",
                 "SD-Rock",
                 "TV Shows",
                 "Voice Memos",
                 "iTunes U",
             ],
    -onchange   => \&selected_item,
);
$cui->draw;
$cui->set_binding( \&exit_dialog , "\cQ");
$cui->mainloop();

sub selected_item {
    my $item = $listbox->get_active_value();
    my $return = $cui->dialog(
        -message   => "You selected item: $item. Do you want to quit?",
        -title     => "Item selected",
        -buttons   => ['yes', 'no'],
    );
    exit 0 if $return;
}

sub exit_dialog {
    my $return = $cui->dialog(
        -message   => "Do you really want to quit?",
        -title     => "Are you sure?",
        -buttons   => ['yes', 'no'],
    );
    exit 0 if $return;
}
```

Comment: I did try this code which I had also found, I installed curses via RPM, and in this test got this error: ./menu2: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./menu2: line 1: `my $cui = Curses::UI->new( -color_support => 1 );'

Comment: Hi. There is a single quote after the semicolon, try to remove it.